# Extracting data from JSON response to list or array in VB.Net

Tags: json, vb.net, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

I don't really understand the make-up of JSON so I am struggling to adapt other answers to suit my needs.  I really hope someone can help?  Specifically I want to get a list or array of "elevations" from the following JSON response in VB.  I have managed to get the response into a string and parsed it but that is as far as I have got.

VB.Net:

```
Imports Newtonsoft.Json.Linq

Dim urlstring As String = urlstring1 & coordstring & urlstring2
Dim srequest As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create(urlstring), HttpWebRequest)
Dim responsestring As String
        'Execute http enquiry
        Try
            Dim sresponse As New StreamReader(srequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
            responsestring = sresponse.ReadToEnd()
            sresponse.Close()
            'MessageBox.Show(responsestring)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Error getting elevations, check internet connection")
            GoTo X
        End Try

Dim ser As JObject = JObject.Parse(responsestring)
```

JSON:

```
{  
   "authenticationResultCode":"ValidCredentials",  
   "brandLogoUri":"http:\/\/dev.virtualearth.net\/Branding\/logo_powered_by.png",  
   "copyright":"Copyright © 2012 Microsoft and its suppliers. All rights reserved. This API cannot be accessed and the content and any results may not be used, reproduced or transmitted in any manner without express written permission from Microsoft Corporation.",  
   "resourceSets":[  
      {  
         "estimatedTotal":1,  
         "resources":[  
            {  
               "__type":"ElevationData:http:\/\/schemas.microsoft.com\/search\/local\/ws\/rest\/v1",  
               "elevations":[1776,1775,1777,1776],  
               "zoomLevel":14  
            }  
         ]  
      }  
   ],  
   "statusCode":200,  
   "statusDescription":"OK",  
   "traceId":"8d57dbeb0bb94e7ca67fd25b4114f5c3"  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use something to help you visualize, like https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/
Collapse all then as you expand write your path.

When you get to {} you type the name, when you get to [] you type number.

YourArray = ser("resourceSets")(0)("resources")(0)("elevations")

Comment: Thank you for this.  I was almost there.  I didn't realise that one set of data would be in a 3rd subset so was just trying to get each token in "elevations" rather than resourcesets:resources:elevations.  It worked a treat once I added the full path.

Answer (score 0):

Adding CruleD's response to my code:

```
Imports Newtonsoft.Json.Linq

Dim urlstring As String = urlstring1 & coordstring & urlstring2
Dim srequest As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create(urlstring), HttpWebRequest)
Dim responsestring As String
'Execute http enquiry
Try
            Dim sresponse As New StreamReader(srequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
            responsestring = sresponse.ReadToEnd()
            sresponse.Close()

Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Error getting elevations, check internet connection")
            GoTo X
End Try

Dim ser As JObject = JObject.Parse(responsestring)
For Each token As JToken In ser("resourceSets")(0)("resources")(0)("elevations")
            'Do something here with each item in the list such as add to an array
            'e.g. elevationarray(tokennumber) = token
            'tokennumber = tokennumber + 1
Next
```